# Jest response mock function not assigning correct response for send and status method

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to write a unit test to a method which has error scenario, throws status as 404 and send method in response returns not found for that scenario. I mocked response method and find One method, validated findOne toHaveBeenCalledWith(), it passes. when checking toHaveBeenCalledWith() for send and status method in response failed. endup with an error, **No of calls:0**

**Error.ts**

```
  static throwError(errorDef?: string | Error | ErrorMessage, fields = FIELDS): never {
    if ((errorDef as APIError)?.fields) {
      throw errorDef;
    }
    response.status(errorDef.statusCode).send({ message: errorDef.message, fields: {} });

  }
```

method.ts

```
testMethod = async (request: Request, response: Response, entityType: EntityType): Promise<void> => {
    tryCatch(async () => {
      // db validation
      const document = await model.findOne({ email: request.query.email }, false);
      if (!document) {
        throwError({
          name: 'Validation Error',
          message: 'Not Found.',
          statusCode: 404,
        });
      }
}
```

test.ts

```
describe('Password Reset', () => {
  // Preparing
  const response: Partial<Response> = {};
  response.status = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(response);
  response.send = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(response);
  // resetSendPasscode Test suite
  describe('testMethod', () => {
    it('should throw error when document not found.', async () => {
      // Preparing
      const request: Partial<Request> = {
        query: {
          email: 'user@gmail.com',
        },
      };
      const spyFindOne = jest.spyOn(userModel.getModel(), 'findOne').mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve(null) as any);
      // Verifying
      await passwordResetController.testMethod(request as Request, response as Response, EntityType.User);
      expect(spyFindOne).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ user_email: 'user@gmail.com' }, false); // this expect block get passed
      expect(response.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(404); 
      expect(response.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ fields: {}, message: 'Not found.' });
      spyFindOne.mockClear();
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: In `throwError()`, shouldn't the `throw` be at the end so that the response status is set before execution stoping?

Comment: Please don't delete the code from your question unless you are sure that the code that you deleted would not help readers of this question to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be fixed if you pass down `response` as an argument to `throwError` (I'm actually not sure why `tsc` doesn't complain when compiling...). So change your method signature to:

```
static throwError(response: Response, errorDef?: string | Error | ErrorMessage, fields = FIELDS): void { ... }
```

and call it with

```
throwError(response, {
  name: 'Validation Error',
  message: 'Not Found.',
  statusCode: 404,
});
```

Comment: I forgot to add error.ts method. To gendralize there is a mthod `throwError` where we send responce. I have updated code above